# Fetching env variables from AWS Secrets within Module to override ConfigSerivce

Tags: nestjs

I've been stuck on this for some time. Ideally I would like the @nestj/config ConfigService (this example I'm just grabbing .env from the file system) to spin up then grab basic env values (NODE_ENV and SECRETS_NAME/SECRETS_REGION) then make a call to secrets to retieve all of the env variables and return a new ConfigService which will be used throughout other modules. I haven't been able to await those secret values:

custom module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SecretsManager } from 'aws-sdk';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useFactory: async () => {
        console.log('initiating config..');
        try {
          const filePath = '../../.env';
          const envFile = path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            '../../',
            '.config',
            filePath,
          );
          const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(envFile));
          if (envConfig.NODE_ENV === 'local') {
            console.log('returning local');
            return new ConfigService({ envFilePath: '.env' });
          }
          const client = new SecretsManager({
            region: envConfig.SECRETS_REGION,
          });
          const secret = await client
            .getSecretValue({ SecretId: envConfig.SECRETS_NAME })
            .promise()
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              return err;
            });
          const existingEnvVars = {
            NODE_ENV: envConfig.NODE_ENV,
            SECRETS_REGION: envConfig.SECRETS_REGION,
            SECRETS_NAME: envConfig.SECRETS_NAME,
          };
          const any = secret as any;
          const secrets = JSON.parse(any.SecretString ?? '');
          const fullVars = { ...existingEnvVars, ...secrets };
          return new ConfigService({
            envFilePath: undefined,
            ignoreEnvFile: true,
            load: [fullVars],
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error fetching user data: ${error.message}`);
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      },
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class AppConfigModule {}
```

and the app.module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppConfigModule } from './config/appconfig.module';
import { OpenAIProvider } from './openai/openai';
import {
  TRANSCRIPTION_SERVICE,
  TranscriptionService,
} from './interfaces/transcription/transcription.service';
import { TranscriptionController } from './interfaces/transcription/transcription.controller';
import { OPENAI_SERVICE, OpenAIService } from './openai/openai.service';
import {
  CONVERSATION_SERVICE,
  ConversationService,
} from './interfaces/conversation/conversation.service';
import {
  HELPERS_SERVICE,
  HelpersService,
} from './common/helpers/helpers.service';
import { UsersService } from './interfaces/users/users.service';
import { UsersController } from './interfaces/users/users.controller';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { PostgresClient } from './database/PostgresClient';
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';
import { OpenaiModule } from './openai/openai.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AppConfigModule, DatabaseModule, AuthModule, OpenaiModule],
  controllers: [TranscriptionController, UsersController],
  providers: [
    OpenAIProvider,
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: TRANSCRIPTION_SERVICE,
      useClass: TranscriptionService,
    },
    {
      provide: OPENAI_SERVICE,
      useClass: OpenAIService,
    },
    {
      provide: HELPERS_SERVICE,
      useClass: HelpersService,
    },
    {
      provide: CONVERSATION_SERVICE,
      useClass: ConversationService,
    },
    UsersService,
    PostgresClient,
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone needs this in the future, I was able to have a custom config service load using serverless env variable or looking at a local.env file depending on if used locally or on the server using useFactory async method returning the custom config:

custom module:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AppConfigService,
      useFactory: async () => {
//async logic
       return new AppConfigService(envConfig)

      },
    },
  ],
  exports: [AppConfigService],
})
export class AppConfigModule {}
```

custom config service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AppConfigService.name);

  constructor(public envVariables: any) {}

  get(key: any) {
    try {
      return this.envVariables[key];
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(
        `Unable to fetch ${key} from envVariables ${this.envVariables}`,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and this module can be imported via imports in app.module.ts and will ensure to load prior to any other modules.